# What causes the failure to detect a click event outside an html element in this Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have been working on an SPA with Vue 3, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB).

I am currently working on a search form.

In `src\components\TopBar.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <!-- More code -->
  <form ref="searchForm" class="search_form w-100 mx-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input v-on:keyup="debounceMovieSearch" v-model="searchTerm" class="form-control search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search movies...">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn" type="button">
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'search']" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div v-if="isSearch" @click="isSearch = false" class="search-results shadow-sm">
      <div v-if="this.movies.length">
        <router-link v-for="movie in movies.slice(0, 10)" :key="movie.id" :to="`/movie/${movie.id}`">
          <SearchItem :movie="movie" />
        </router-link>
      </div>

      <div v-else>
        <p class="m-0 p-2 text-center">No movies found for this search</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import env from '../env';
  import SearchItem from './SearchItem.vue';

  export default defineComponent({
        name: 'TopBar',

    components: {SearchItem},

    data() {
      return {
        searchForm: ref(null),
        isSearch: false,
        searchTerm: '',
        timeOutInterval: 1000,
        movies: []
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      this.windowEvents();
    },

    methods: {
      windowEvents() {
        window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          if (!(this.$refs.searchForm as HTMLElement).value.contains(event.target)){
            console.log('click outside');
          }
        });
      },
      
      debounceMovieSearch() {
        setTimeout(this.doMovieSearch, this.timeOutInterval)
      },

      doMovieSearch() {
        if (this.searchTerm.length > 2) {
            this.isSearch = true;
            axios.get(`${env.api_url}/search/movie?api_key=${env.api_key}&query=${this.searchTerm}`).then(response => {
            this.movies = response.data.results;
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
      },
    }
  });
</script>
```

[image]

The goal is to **hide the search results lists if the user clicks outside the form**. To achiwve this, I have:

```
windowEvents() {
 window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (!(this.$refs.searchForm as HTMLElement).value.contains(event.target)){
    console.log('click outside');
  }
 });
}
```

#### The problem

The method above throes the error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two ways to declare template refs.

In composition API, you declare a template ref by declaring a ref and setting the variable name to a `ref` attribute on a tag. Then Vue will link the node to the variable, and you can access it through the `.value` property of the ref.

In options API, you just set the `ref` attribute on the tag and use `this.$refs` to access the node. `this.$refs` is a Proxy that gives you the nodes directly (there is no `.value` property).

You are using options API, so the line in should be:

```
 if (!(this.$refs.searchForm as HTMLFormElement).contains(event.target as Node|null)) { // no ".value"
```

You can also remove the `searchForm` ref from `data`.